Does $ H/H_0 $ embed in the Weyl group? (Here $ H $ is a positive dimensional closed subgroup of the compact simple Lie group $ G $)
Let $ G $ be a compact simple Lie group with Weyl group $ W(G) $. Let $ H $ be a positive dimensional closed subgroup of $ G $. Does $ H/H_0 $ embed into $ W(G) $?
I've checked this for connected subgroups $ H $ of compact simple Lie groups of small rank like
$$
 SO(3), SO(5), SO(6), SU(2), SU(3), SU(4), G_2 
$$
and it seems to be true. Is it true in general?
Note the assumption that $ H $ is positive dimensional is important. Otherwise there are easy counterexamples, for example take $ H $ to be the icosahedral $ A_5 $ subgroup of $ G=SO(3) $. Then $ H/H_0\cong A_5 $ does not embed in $ W(G) $, which is cyclic $ 2 $.
Similarly, as Moishe Kohan pointed out correctly below, we must assume $ G $ is simple, otherwise there are simple counterexamples like the take $ H $ to be the central product $ U(1) \times SL(2,5) / \pm I $ subgroup of $ U(2) $ given by the binary icosahedral group together with all phases $ e^{i \theta} I $. Then $ H/H_0 \cong A_5 $ again does not embed in the Weyl group of $ U(2) $, which is cyclic $ 2 $.
More generally I assume this works for any simple algebraic group $ G $, but compact groups are algebraic so that seemed like a good place to start.
Update: Now that I think about the comment from Moishe Kohan more I think he already has the answer. For example we can take $ H=A_5 \times SO(2) $ as a subgroup of $ G=SO(5) $ and then $ H/H_0\cong A_5 $ does not embed in the Weyl group of $ SO(5) $, which is $ D_4 $ the dihedral group of the square.

This is clearly false for $SO(3)\times S^1$ (and, hence, for $SO(4)$).

@MoisheKohan Ah very good catch, let me add an assumption that $ G $ is simple

Unless your simple (connected) Lie group $G$ is locally isomorphic to $SO(3)$, your conjecture about subgroups is false. Indeed, suppose that $G$ has rank $\ge 2$. Then it contains the torus $T^2=S^1\times S^1$ (as a closed  subgroup). Now, take a finite cyclic subgroup $C_n< S^1$ and $H:= C_n\times S^1< T^2$. Then $H/H_0\cong C_n$ has order $n$ which can be arbitrarily large. But the Weyl group $W$ of $G$ is finite. Hence, for large $n$, $H/H_0$ cannot be isomorphic to a subgroup of $W$.
